# What is the PREEMPT in the ssh message?

Tags: ssh

When I'm login into the raspberry through ssh I'm receiving the following message

```
Linux raspberrypi 3.2.27+ #250 PREEMPT Thu Oct 18 19:03:02 BST 2012 armv6l
```

What does it mean the `PREEMPT`? Is that real time kernel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PREEMPT` seems to stand for "[kernel preemption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_preemption)". [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/817094) explain in a clear English what is a preemptive kernel:

> Preemptive multitasking - **Running several processes/threads on a single processor, creating the illusion that they run concurrently when actually each is allocated small multiplexed time slices to run in.** A process is "preempted" when it is scheduled out of execution and waits for the next time slice to run in.
>
> A preemptive kernel is one that can be interrupted in the middle of a executing code - for instance in response for a system call - to do other things and run other threads, possible that are not in the kernel.
>   The main advantage in a preemptive kernel is that sys-calls do not block the entire system. if a sys-call takes a long time to finish then it doesn't mean the kernel can't do anything else in this time.
>   The main disadvantage is that this introduces more complexity to the kernel code, having to handle more end-cases, perform more fine grained locking or use lock-less structures and algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

It means that you have preempted kernel version. More info about preempted kernel could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/817059/1059429).

This option could be enabled while compiling kernel with option:

```
CONFIG_PREEMPT=y
```

Comment: Wow! I think we asked the same thing to Google :)

Comment: :) I have worked with both preemptive and non-preemptive kernels... so I had some info about those. BTW this was quite straightforward without asking Google :)

Comment: I have just noticed your link to StackOverflow. Indeed similar answer. +1 for your @Morgan